# Simulating stopPropagation with CSS

Tags: html, css

So I'm wanting to achieve a `stopPropagation()` on elements i don't know what they will be, but i want to make a global handler so bubbling wont work but with css. pretty fair ee :P

```html
<style>
    #ok {
      padding: 4px;
      background: #333;
      pointer-events: none;
    }

    a {
      pointer-events: all;
    }
  </style>
```

Here my style, where the container has pointer-events: none, and the child i want to click is a, but i don't want to trigger ok container.

Here is my html:

```html
<div id='ok'>
    <a href="#" id='beni'>
      Kur ta klikon nuk bohet trigger
    </a>
</div>
```

Where i container it and i add padding for testing purpose.

And last is the events so we can track the clicks being made:

```js
function playerClick(event) {
  el_canvas.textContent += '|';
}

function buttonClick(event) {
  if (el_stopPropagation.checked) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
  el_button.textContent += '|';
}

el_player.addEventListener('click', playerClick)
el_button.addEventListener('click', buttonClick)
```

```html
<fieldset id="el_player">
  <div id="el_canvas">"Player" clicked: </div>
  <button id="el_button">Button clicked: </button>
</fieldset>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="el_stopPropagation">
  Stop propagation in button's listener
</label>
```

Comment: That `pointer-events: none` will not prevent pointer events of descendants from bubbling up and then triggering event handlers registered for the parent, is already explained under https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#none

Comment: Yes, but wondering if someone has something similar to fix the issue i have, where I can't use stopPropagation(), but thanks.

Comment: Your code doesn't even include `stopPropagation()` so we don't know where this is coming from.

Comment: I don't know _what_ you actually want to fix, in your _real_ use case. This construed example here seems rather unsuited to actually illustrate that.

Comment: I think it is quite clear what OP needs to achieve -- prevent parent's listener from child's handler, what is easy in JS when both are registered for bubbling phase; added simple demo to the question. What is not so clear is their concrete setup and relation to CSS.